# Why does my formatter function receive the index instead of the axis value?

Tags: python, pandas, matplotlib

I am playing around with creating graphs with pandas and matplotlib while following [a tutorial](https://pbpython.com/effective-matplotlib.html). I have no real world problem to solve with this question, I am just trying to understand.

I was trying to shorten some of the names on the axis of a bar plot, but for some reason it looks like the index is getting passed into my formatter function.

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jake', 'Finn'], 'Score':[4, 6]})

def does_nothing(value, pos):
    return value

fix, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='bar', x="Name", y="Score", ax=ax)
formatter = FuncFormatter(does_nothing)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Without trying to format the axis, I get what I would expect - Jake and Finn on my axis. But if I pass it through a formatter and I get 0 and 1. Why is this happening? How do I then get the string?

Answer (score 0):

Use this instead, ax=ax resets it to the index:

```
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import FuncFormatter

df = pd.DataFrame({'Name':['Jake', 'Finn'], 'Score':[4, 6]})

def does_nothing(value, pos):
    return value

fix, ax = plt.subplots()
df.plot(kind='bar', x="Name", y="Score")
formatter = FuncFormatter(does_nothing)
ax.xaxis.set_major_formatter(formatter)
```

Comment: If I do that (in a Jupyter notebook anyway) I get 2 plots - one blank one and one as I expect. 

But, if ax=ax resets the axis to an index, why does this not happen if I comment out the last two lines in the original code?